# Jenkins pipeline: How to checkout repository without triggering polling or tracking changes?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

My project consists of multiple git repositories. One main repository, and other helper repositories. In jenkins pipeline, I want to `checkout scm:` all of them, but I am only interested in tracking changes, and polling from the main repository - others clutter the changelog and cause other infrastructure problems (it's a big project).

I thought about simply checking out remaining repositories in `sh` blocks to skip "features" I don't want, but I'll have to duplicate config, and somehow pass credentials - generally I'd like pipelines to do the work for me.

Expected result:
`checkout scm` does not cause changelog to appear, or cause polling from said repo down the line.

Is there a way to archive this using configuration, instead of hiding checkout logic from pipeline using `sh`step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you checkout the other repositories, you can disable the changelog and polling with the optional arguments to the class. For example, given a helper repository called `helper`:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
          branches: [[name: '*/master']],
          userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'http://git-server/user/helper.git']]
          changelog: false,
          poll: false
])
```

and then the changelog and polling will be disabled for the `helper` repository. You can duplicate this usage for all your other helper repositories to disable their changelog and polling.

Check the GitSCM Pipeline Step [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code in Jenkinsfile:

```
checkout scm: scm, poll: false, changelog: false
```

Comment: Documentation at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/