# Disable changelog in Jenkins pipeline checkout

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that checks out specific commits from several different repos. I would like to disable the calculation of the `changeSet` (changelog) since the /api/json call to the job takes a long time to compute (and the changelog is not important for that job in any case).

In the pipeline I'm checking out the code with:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
branches: [[name: commitHash]],
doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
submoduleCfg: [],
changelog: false,
poll: false,
userRemoteConfigs: [[url: gitUrl]]])
```

I thought that setting `changelog` to false would prevent that, but when I call the `/api/json` page for the job I can still see the `changeSet` populated.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Just to be clear, the change logs I see for that job are related to all the jobs I'm checking out with the code above within the pipeline.
I don't mind to have the changelog of the git repository where the Jenkinsfile is checked out from, but I don't want to include the changelogs of all the projects checked out as part of the pipeline stages.

Does the `lightweight checkout` mode in the pipeline configuration has anything to do with it?

Comment: That is the `changelog` disable for the checkout performed during the job and not for the job itself.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, how you disable the changeset for the job itself?

Comment: I believe that `lightweight checkout` mode is unrelated. That just checks out the specified Jenkinsfile, rather than the whole repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the changelog. That was already answered here:
[Jenkins pipeline: How to checkout repository without triggering polling or tracking changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634438/jenkins-pipeline-how-to-checkout-repository-without-triggering-polling-or-track)

You could use also the git command directly from a sh block.

Comment: I believe the question was about jenkins pipeline defined via DSL rather than about the checkout step when the job is running.